# Embedded C Parse Server migration serverURL

Tags: linux, parse-platform, embedded, parse-server

I want to try to change embedded c linux ParseClient to point to my heroku hosted parser url but I couldn't find any command like Parse.serverURL = "http:parse.herokuapp.com/parse" like iOS, Androind, and etc. in this example https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Parse-Server-Guide#using-parse-sdks-with-parse-server

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version 1.0.4 of the sdk there is a [new initialize method](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-embedded-sdks/blob/8c2b9a70ed149bc8060d17ca435a72cb9622a516/include/parse.h#L150) that also takes a serverUrl.

`ParseClient parseInitializeWithServerURL(const char *applicationId,  const char *clientKey, const char *serverURL);`

It seems like everything should work, but the issue for this is still open on github so I'm not entirely sure. You can follow it [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-embedded-sdks/issues/63).